# Вера в себя - фразеологизм?

Tags: фразеология

Можно ли считать выражение "вера в себя" фразеологизмом?

Answer (score 3):

Нельзя.

> Фразеологизм – устойчивое словосочетание, оборот речи, выражение,
> значение которого не складывается из значений составляющих его слов;
> идиома.

Вера в себя – клише, штамп. Так часто употребляется, что и употреблять-то уже неприлично. Разве что разговаривая с ребёнком, сомневающимся в своих возможностях.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149870/discussion-on-answer-by-galina-avanesova----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 3):

**ДИАЛОГ**

— Вера в себя — это **фразеологизм?**
— **Нет!** Кто-то сказал однажды, другие стали повторять.
— Но тогда это **устойчивость и воспроизводимость**.
— Этого мало! Определенные черты фразеологизма есть, **но не все**. Это **устойчивое** сочетание, довольно часто воспроизводимое в речи.
— Но нет **переносного** значения: я верю в себя, верю с свои способности, в собственные возможности. **Состав свободный**, можно добавить определение или дополнение. Понятное **управление**: верить (во что?) в себя, в удачу и т. д. **Образности нет,** просто частотный оборот.
— Как же нет? Можно верить в удачу, в домовых и т. д. Но верить в  себя — это что? **Верить в то, что я существую**? Образность есть!
—  Тогда **историчности** не хватает.
— Но уже много времени прошло, кто это сочетание **первым сказал**?
— Ну хорошо, пусть это будет **фразеологизм (фразеологическое сочетание).**

**[Фразеологизмы с "себя"](https://burido.ru/razvitie-i-obuchenie/515-frazeologizmy-s-sebya)**

**[Нацкорпус](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CnQiLgosCioKJHByaV9jYXQ60YXRg9C00L7QttC10YHRgtCy0LXQvdC90LDRjxoCCAEqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIQofCh0KA3JlcRIWChTQstC10YDQsCDQsiDRgdC10LHRjzAA)** ("вера в себя")

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

**Фразеологизм** — это устойчивое по составу и структуре образное выражение из двух и более слов.

Выделяют **три основных вида** фразеологизмов: идиомы, фразеологические единства и фразеологические сочетания ([**skysmart.ru**](https://skysmart.ru/articles/russian/frazeologizm)).

1. **Фразеологические сращения (идиомы)** — устойчивые выражения, которые имеют **смысл только в неизменном виде**: «бить баклуши», то есть бездельничать.
2. **Фразеологические единства** — устойчивые образные выражения, смысл которых понятен из смысла отдельных слов. Например, обороты «грызть гранит науки» или «попасться на удочку» можно понять даже при переводе на другой язык. **Смысл** фразеологического единства **не потеряется**, если заменить «удочку» на «крючок» или вставить в оборот лишнее слово.
3. **Фразеологические сочетания** — устойчивые, но гибкие обороты, смысл которых определяется через **отдельные ключевые слова.** При этом не ключевые слова можно заменять синонимами. Пример: можно «умирать от любви», а можно «умирать от восторга» — смысл обоих словосочетаний понятен.

**Признаки фразеологизмов**

У фразеологизма как самостоятельной лексической единицы языка есть свои отличительные черты.

1. Фразеологизм состоит из **двух и более слов**.
2. У фразеологизмов есть **устойчивый состав**.
   Лексический состав фразеологизма нельзя никак изменять, так как при этом теряется его смысл.
3. Главный признак фразеологизмов — **воспроизводимость**.
   Мы не придумываем фразеологизмы в процессе диалога, а берем их из языковой памяти.
4. **Переносное значение** фразеологизмов сложилось **исторически**.
   Иногда переносное значение фразеологизма нельзя понять, не обратившись **к истории** его возникновения. Например, фразу «на козе не подъедешь» трудно понять, особенно иностранцам, которые изучают русский язык.
5. Все слова одного фразеологизма — это **один член предложения**.