# Помогите определить тип фразеологизма по Виноградову

Tags: фразеология

Скажите, пожалуйста, "давать задний ход" – это какой тип фразеологизма по Виноградову?

Comment: Этот сайт не для домашних заданий, извините.

Comment: Недавно на форуме обсуждали такую же тему  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476800/Вера-в-себя-фразеологизм   Два ответа, два голоса за сам вопрос

Comment: Это не фразеологизм, это техническая терминология.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, это **фразеологическое единство:** можно отметить наличие **образности,** а это важный признак.

На **сращение/идиому**  не похоже, так как значение каждого слова **понятно** пользователям. В то же время замена слов вряд ли возможна, то есть это **целостная** конструкция, в отличие от фразеологического **сочетания.**

**[По Виноградову](https://book-science.ru/humanities/semanticheskaja-klassifikacija-frazeologizmov.html#:%7E:text=%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%3A,%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B)** существует  **три типа** фразеологизмов: фразеологические сращения, фразеологические единства и фразеологические сочетания.

Фразеологизмы **первой и второй** групп обладают **слитным** фразеологическим значением, являются **целостными** наименованием явления действительности.

Фразеологические **сочетания** представляют собой семантические и синтаксические **членимые единицы.**

**[Из Интернета](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3406734-chto-oznachaet-vyrazhenie-dat-zadnij-hod.html)**

1. Фразеологизм "***дать задний ход***" означает отказ от убеждений, от ранее высказанного, от обещанного. Причиной может быть осознание невозможности или большой сложности осуществления ранее высказанного.

Синоним – ***идти на попятную.*** Это означает "идти на попятную". То есть, отказаться от своих слов. Например, что-нибудь пообещал и не хочешь или не можешь это сделать. или боишься - причин может быть множество.

2. **[Фразеологические единства](https://studfile.net/preview/7625615/page:19/)** – это такие фразеологические единицы, **целостное** значение которых мотивировано значениями их компонентов. Примеры единств: ***тянуть лямку, мелко плавать, зарыть талант в землю, высосать из пальца, водить за нос*** и т. П. Один из характерных признаков фразеологических единств – их **образность.**

Так, говорящему понятно, почему о безвольном человеке можно сказать мокрая курица: вид мокрой, побывавшей в воде курицы жалок. **Наличие образности** отличает фразеологические единства от омонимичных им **свободных** сочетаний слав.

Так, в предложении Мальчик намылил себе голову туалетным мылом сочетание намылил голову – **свободное**, оно имеет прямой смысл и лишено какой-либо образности; в предложении Боюсь, как бы начальник не намылил ему голову за опоздание сочетание намылил голову употреблено образно и представляет собой фразеологическое единство.

Comment: дать **передний ход**, дать **задний ход**. "Отдаются кормовые швартовы; дается передний ход./Если у вашего судна пассивный руль, его надо повернуть в сторону от причала и, включив передний ход на самых малых оборотах," - это вообще не фразеологизм никакой, а название технических режимов работы двигателя. с идти на попятную, он рядом не лежал.

Comment: Вы изучали фразеологию явно не Виноградову.  Изначально эти выражения рядом не лежали, но потом произошло их переосмысление и сближение. Это я вам со знанием дела говорю)) И  еще.  Вот я наблюдаю за вами (потому что  наблюдатель по жизни) и делаю вывод. Вы – путешественник во времени, а к нам случайно попали.   Из прошлого или из будущего? Моряком, наверное, были, а то еще и похуже) Признайтесь, а я никому не расскажу)

Comment: "Всё то, что со мной творится -/ лишь тень моей прошлой жизни./ Я был моряком торговым/ (та соль до сих пор во рту)..."

Comment: Вот-вот, и с этого места подробнее, пжста.  (Стих я уже прочитала.)  Но я не в переносном смысле говорю, а в прямом. Так откуда вы? Знаете много чего из другого времени, но  не из нашего. Рассуждаете странно, не как мы.

Comment: из мира грёз с цикличным временем, а вы из мира объективной реальности с осевым временем.

Comment: Красиво, но я вам не верю...