# Можно ли фразеологизм назвать идиомой?

Tags: фразеология

1. Большой толковый словарь

**ИДИОМА**, -ы; ж. [греч. idiōma - своеобразное выражение от idios — особый, отдельный]. Лингв. Устойчивое словосочетание, оборот речи, выражение, значение которого не складывается из значений составляющих его слов; **фразеологизм**. Идиомы народной речи. Типичная и. Идиоматический; Идиоматичный

**ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЗМ**, -а; м. Лингв. Устойчивое словосочетание, оборот речи, выражение, значение которого не складывается из значений составляющих его слов; **идиома.**

2. По словарю получается, что термины **взаимозаменяемы**. С другой стороны можно услышать: это не идиома, а фразеологизм. А что такое **фразеология** вообще?   **ФРАЗА**, -ы; ж. [от греч. phrasis — выражение, оборот речи]. Фразеология языка — это ведь не только фразеологические обороты.

**Вопрос:** Как ***правильно*** использовать эти термины в речи, чтобы вас поняли ***правильно***?

**[Обсуждение темы на форуме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476800/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8F-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC) (виды фразеологизмов)**

[Еще одна тема](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476900/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Фразеологизм - это общее, родовое понятие.

Идиома - понятие видовое. Это ***одно из*** фразеологических средств.

К фразелогии отнести можно, положим, крылатые слова, фразовые речения, *идиомы*, пословицы, поговорки, да по сути любые спаянные сочетания с единым смыслом. Все эти лексические явления есть фразеологизмы.

Иными словами, идиома - это точно фразеологизм, однако не всякий фразеологизм идиома.

Можно сказать, что "бить баклуши" - это фразеологизм. Если сказать, что "бить баклуши" - это идиома, то это будет лишь уточнение разновидности фразеологизма.

Можно сказать, что "произвести подсчёт" - это цельное сочетание, фразеологизм. А если уточнять, то "произвести подсчёт" - это фразовое речение.

Comment: Фразеологические сращения обычно называют идиомой. Бить баклуши — идиома.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий:**

Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня.

Итак, термины ***фразеология, фразеологизм, идиома*** могут иметь обобщенное и конкретное (более узкое) значение, но как их правильно **использовать** в речи?

1. С одной стороны, **фразеология** — это  совокупность языковых средств вообще, а с другой — **устойчивые** сочетания, которые называют **идиоматикой**. К примеру, можно говорить о русской или английской фразеологии. Или сказать кому-то: вы не знаете русскую фразеологию (правда, это не очень вежливо))

**ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЯ**, -и; ж. [от греч. phrásis — выражение, оборот речи и lógos - учение]. **1. Лингв. Раздел** языкознания, изучающий устойчивые словосочетания; идиоматика (1 зн.). Теория фразеологии. **2. Лингв. Совокупность устойчивых** словосочетаний, оборотов речи и выражений, свойственных какому-л. языку; идиоматика (2 зн.). Французская ф. **3. Совокупность приёмов словесного выражения,** свойственных кому-л. или какой-л. эпохе, политическому движению и т.п. Религиозная, националистическая ф. Демагогическая ф.

2. **Свободное** словосочетание (***произвести расчет***)  не является фразеологизмом, а напротив, противопоставляется  ему.  Слово **«идиома»** тоже используется на часто, а по делу (как частный вид фразеологизма) или же в определенном контексте.
3. **По Виноградову** существует **три типа** фразеологизмов: фразеологические сращения, фразеологические единства и фразеологические сочетания. По толковому словарю **идиома** соответствует фразеологическому **сращению** в классификации Виноградова,  и тогда, к примеру,  ***бить баклуши*** — это идиома.
4. Вопрос был задан после обсуждения другой темы (о сочетании "не покладая рук"). Там его называли **фразеологизмом** (вероятно, в общем смысле), но в ответе говорится, что это **идиома**. Как правильно говорить  — не очень понятно. Какая-то **разница** между этими выражениями есть даже в **обобщенном** смысле (когда они вроде бы заменяют друг друга), но сформулировать это сложно.