Детские вопросы к выражению «где наше не пропадало»
Вот что мы обнаружили.
• В словарях:
где наше не пропадало = где наша не пропада́ла! Восклицание, сопровождающее какое-либо рискованное начинание;
возглас самоутешения или утешения других при потере или убытке;
народное выражение решимости идти на риск.
• В Нацкорпусе (самое раннее):
Снова водворилось молчание; только карты хляскали по столам, да по временам раздавались восклицания игроков: «пас»; «а ну, где наше не пропадало!» и т. д. или краткие разговоры вроде следующих... (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Помпадуры и помпадурши (1863–1874));
И я согласился бы с тем, чтобы на другой же день жениться. Где наша не пропадала! Вижу ее во сне (Л. А. Андреев. Дневник (1900)).
• В пословицах русского народа В. И. Даля: счастье, удача / клевета, напраслина.
• Остались вопросы:
где не пропадало и почему, собственно, не пропадало;
наше, наша — это кто или что (и почему же нет наш, наши);
это всё-таки пословица или фразеологизм;
когда впервые было использовано;
каково значение пословицы в разделе "клевета, напраслина" (ведь в словарях его нет)?

«клевета, напраслина» … === Римма, в каком из изданий пословиц у Даля есть такой раздел?

Вот здесь, Слава.  (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/63/%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%90) Я в вопросе дала ссылку, только надо было найти из многих словарей.

Да, посмотрел, и в первом издании «Пословиц» (1861) то же самое.

В том числе и поэтому задан вопрос. Мы удивились, потому что в словарях нет значения выражения, связанного с клеветой или напраслиной.

Я думаю, эта фраза получилась из притчи о пшенице и плевелах.

Я задал ваш вопрос   GPT chat-у и вот ответ.
Интересный разбор! Фраза «Где наша не пропадала» действительно обросла вопросами и нюансами. Попробую ответить по каждому пункту:
Почему «где не пропадало» и что значит «не пропадало»
Выражение уходит корнями в народное восприятие неизбежного риска и смелости перед лицом опасности. Русский язык имеет множество подобных выражений, которые играют с темой «пропажи» или «утраты» как синонима преодоления (например, «пропади оно пропадом!»). «Где не пропадало» — это своего рода утверждение неуязвимости, метафора устойчивости в самых непростых обстоятельствах. Смысл в том, что когда-то уже рисковали, не пропали, значит и теперь справимся.
Почему «наша», а не «наш» или «наше»
Существуют версии о происхождении выражения, относящиеся к солдатскому фольклору, где слова «наша» и «боевая подруга» нередко обозначали «жизнь», «душу» или «смелость». «Наша» могло означать также идею «наша доля» (судьба, удача), но в обиходе иронично могла означать и «шальная душа», и даже коллективный дух компании. То есть «наша» не обозначает что-то конкретное, а скорее отражает коллективный дух авантюры, некий общий жизненный шанс, который «не пропадал» и раньше.
Пословица или фразеологизм?
Здесь скорее фразеологизм, но очень близкий к пословице, ведь он активно используется и как народное мудрое изречение. От пословиц его отличает отсутствие конкретной морали или вывода; это скорее эмоциональный комментарий к риску, нежели руководство к действию.
Первое употребление
Нацкорпус и другие источники, похоже, подтверждают, что в печати выражение появилось в XIX веке (например, у Салтыкова-Щедрина и Андреева). Однако само выражение, скорее всего, бытовало в устной речи задолго до этого.
Клевета, напраслина в «Пословицах русского народа» В.И. Даля.
Этот момент наиболее интересен и сложен для толкования, так как в современном понимании связь с «клеветой» не очевидна. Однако Даль иногда группировал выражения по смежным концепциям. Возможная логика такова: народные выражения, связанные с напраслиной и ложными обвинениями, часто были оборотами для самооправдания. К примеру, при ситуации, где кого-то могли оклеветать или ложно обвинить, могла прозвучать фраза «где наша не пропадала» в духе готовности принять несправедливое обвинение — мол, «и не к таким трудностям привыкли». То есть, даже под напраслиной или клеветой, говорящий демонстрирует непропадающую «нашу» стойкость.
В целом, фраза осталась в языке как напоминание о том, что народная стойкость и готовность к риску — это нечто, что уже «не пропадало» раньше и не пропадет в будущем.

Не согласна с ответом по фразеологизму.  Эо фразеологическая единица, но по классификации Виноградова он не пройдет. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/476800/Вера-в-себя-фразеологизм  Там нет переносного значения, фраза имеет прямой, хотя и обобщенный смысл.  Пропущенные слова легко домысливаются пользователями, например: Наша сторона взяла вверх. Это скорее поговорка, а может, приговорка.  Смешные приговорки https://stihi.ru/2022/11/27/3758


Вадим Сыван https://proza.ru/2014/08/26/506
ГДЕ НАША НЕ ПРОПАДАЛА?!
    *Где наша не пропадала?! Да только там, где нас 
     ещё не было… Говорите, что у вас – всё хорошо? 
     Тогда мы идём к вам…*

А. С. Пушкин. Пир во время чумы
     Все, все, что гибелью грозит,
     Для сердца смертного таит
     Неизъяснимы наслажденья...
     Итак, — хвала тебе, Чума,
     Нам не страшна могилы тьма,
     Нас не смутит твое призванье!

ОТВЕТ
"О НОВОМ ПРОЧТЕНИИ" пословицы в разделе "клевета, напраслина" у Даля (с продолжением):
Где наше ни пропадало, да так и не пропало.
Уступительное значение, частица НИ: Хотя часто пропадало, да пока еще не пропало (то есть напрасно пропадало).
Это мой вариант, но, возможно, он действительно существовал, если пословица помещена в раздел "напраслина". Остается в литературе поискать.
Но всё же утвердился вариант риторического восклицания с частицей НЕ (где только наше не пропадало!) с надеждой на благоприятный исход, на удачу (более краткий и выразительный).
КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО?
А по-разному правильно.
Снова водворилось молчание; только карты хляскали по столам, да по временам раздавались восклицания игроков: «пас»; «а ну, где наше не пропадало!»  Значение: где наше добро/имущество и т. п. не пропадало! То есть то, что принадлежит нам, связано с нами.
И я согласился бы с тем, чтобы на другой же день жениться. Где наша не пропадала!  Значение: Где наша гвардия/братия и т. п не пропадала! То есть мы сами.
По грамматике это субстантивированное местоимение наш в форме среднего или женского рода: наше, наш. Сравнить: Наш брат охотник куда не заходит (сходная фразеология).
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.  Надо сказать, что прогулки по Сети не принесли  мне какого-либо результата, чтобы можно было объяснить две разные формы) Да я изначально была уверена в этом. Наши люди спокойно перешагивают через такие "препятствия" на пути к знаниям.
ПОСЛОВИЦА, ПОГОВОРКА, ФРАЗЕОЛОГИЗМ
Все вопросы отправляем в Нейросеть. Вот, например: пословица или поговорка отличие; пословица или фразеологизм.
Таким образом, основное отличие в том, что пословица — это законченное высказывание, оформленное как предложение, а фразеологизм — устойчивое словосочетание с переносным смыслом.
Пословица — это целое предложение, а поговорка — лишь часть предложения, фраза или ярко окрашенное словосочетание. Например: «Лучше один раз увидеть, чем сто раз услышать» (пословица) и «Не всё коту масленица» (поговорка).
Похоже на  поговорку, но пусть будет пословицей)  Но не фразеологизм.
КТО СКАЗАЛ ПЕРВЫМ? И ЧТО ЭТО ЗНАЧИТ?
А это трудно сказать) Рисковый (рискованный) вариант описан в разных выражениях и на разных языках)
Предполагаются два значения: Почему бы не рискнуть! В крайнем случае невелика потеря!
Английская мудрость: We'll find a way out —  with luck or without. Мы найдем выход —  с удачей или без. Уверенно звучит!
А это синонимы: Эх, была не была; будь, что будет; либо пан, либо пропал; семь бед —  один ответ; риск — благородное дело; двум смертям не бывать, а одной не миновать. Пан или пропал! риск дело благородное и т. д.
Таково общее мнение, но есть фантазеры, которые могут увидеть такой смысл: «Где наша не пропадала»: сохранение наследия прошлого.
ОТВЕТ НА КОММЕНТАРИЙ
А как сказать: Где наш брат не пропадал? Для этого уже есть формулировка где наш брат охотник, студент и т. д. Где наши люди не пропадали? Слишком банально.
Закрепилось то, что было в какой-то мере образным, а также узнаваемым в качестве обобщения: наше – для неодуш. предметов, а наша – для лиц. У местоимений наш (наш человек) и наши (наши люди) нет нужного значения обобщенности, можно подумать, что речь идет о каких-то конкретных отношениях.

Спасибо за интерес к вопросу! / Значение: Где наша гвардия не пропадала! ...наш в форме среднего или женского рода: наше, наша. Наверное, так? / Почему же тогда нет ни наш, ни наши? В Нацкорпусе только один пример: Жаль, конечно, последние деньги, но где наши не пропадали... (И. И. Моргулес. Записки обжоры // «Уральская новь», 2002).

Простите, ничего не поняла про "И насчет ТЕМЫ" и про слеш. У Даля эта пословица внесена и в раздел счастье — удача, и в раздел клевета — напраслина. Повторяю ссылки: (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/152/%D0%A1%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%A2%D0%AC%D0%95) и (https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dahl_proverbs/63/%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%92%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%90)

Да? Так я же не видела) Тогда так (пословица от меня, надо в список к Далю внести) Наше много пропадало, да так и не пропало.

Я думаю, эта фраза получилась из притчи о пшенице и плевелах и следующей, о горчичном зерне.
То есть в притче пшеница - она. С другой стороны её так же назвали "зерно" - оно.  Потом могли назвать "божья благодать" - опять она. Однако "наше/наша" появилось несколько позже, видимо с "наше" звучала не так красиво, потому что получалось "наше богатство, состояние и тп.", а "наша" могла быть душа.

Истинно, истинно говорю вам: если пшеничное зерно, пав в землю, не
умрет, то останется одно; а если умрет, то принесет много плода.
Любящий душу свою погубит ее; а ненавидящий душу свою в мире сем
сохранит ее в жизнь вечную. 12.24-25 Иоанн.


Ваш ответ напомнил мне стихотворение Р. Бернса "Джон Ячменное Зерно": Трех королей разгневал он, И было решено, Что навсегда погибнет Джон Ячменное Зерно". Но здесь скорее неустрашимость, вызов врагам. Что касается пословицы, то стремление к риску мне кажется какой-то русской ментальностью.  Хотела найти афоризмы на  эту тему в античной, европейской литературе или священных писаниях, но ничего интересного не попалось.

И еще мне думается,  что в текстах русских классиков был другой оттенок значения, что-то вроде " не буду жалеть о пропавшем имуществе, еще наживу".  https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/где+наша+не+пропадала  А вот в современной литературе появилось именно пренебрежение к  риску в игре, надежда выиграть.  Совсем современное:  — Решаешь кроссворды ручкой? Ты сегодня самонадеян… — Что за жизнь без риска! ))

@Sharon почитал немного Бернса в оригинале, там в последней строфе упомянуто, что речь идет о Шотландии, тут вспомнил, что у Шотландцев сложные отношения с короной, и стихотворение приобретает весьма политическое звучание) и форму заговора, под видом попойки. И легко находится статья, что Бернс мог быть весьма радикален к олигархам, были некоторые его стихотворения которые не публиковались : https://www.theguardian.com/books/2016/jan/25/robert-burns-radical-burns-night

"Макилванни видит в раннем Бёрнсе «проповедника адского пламени, осуждающего безнравственность богатых, борющегося с угнетением с помощью христианских ценностей» и нападающего на «коррупцию и некомпетентность правящей элиты», например, на землевладельцев, играющих в карты, в «Двух собаках»." https://www.theguardian.com/books/2003/jan/25/featuresreviews.guardianreview7

Я тут почитала немного про Бёрнса, а вы проверьте) Он не любил англичан и своих тоже, если они "вельможи, церковные ханжи и свора привилегированных  джентльменов".  "Мы сталь английскую не раз
В сраженьях притупили, Но золотом английским нас На торжище купили". // "К политике будь слеп и глух, Коль ходишь ты в заплатах. Ты знаешь: зрение и слух Удел одних богатых". // А еще он был не только бедным веселым фермером, но и акцизным чиновником. А почему такой стих: Есть пляски разные у нас В горах моей отчизны, Но лучший пляс, чертовский пляс Сплясал в аду акцизный!

Еще интересно: Здесь Джон покоится в тиши.
Конечно, только тело... Но, говорят, оно души  И прежде не имело! // Спросила у нейросети про «Джона», есть ли там политические намеки. Сеть зависла, но потом отвечала, что намеки не обнаружены. Потом передумала и ответила: Да, в стихотворении Роберта Бёрнса «Джон Ячменное Зерно» присутствуют политические намёки. История проникнута романтическим пафосом и революционным духом. «Три короля» в контексте стиха превращаются просто в королей-тиранов. Главный герой, чьё нарицательное имя вынесено в название стиха, символизирует нац. дух и осв. движение.

@Sharon ведь может и выдать, когда захочет) Про души не имело, я лучше в письме напишу, а то тут за полит пропаганду сочтут)

Жаль, что мало чего поняла, но  — спасибо!

@РиммаМихайлова , спрашивайте, может смогу пояснить.)

А еще
Наша взяла!

фразеологизм.
Где наша не пропадала тоже фразеологизм, похоже. Во-первых, иначе трудно объяснить, что за наша (ладно еще наше). Хотя изначально наше было наверное"). Во-вторых, пословицы обычно несут какой-то смысл/посыл. Тут же его нет, просто стенание/восклицание/утешение.
Можно предположить, что сначала было наше, потом сразу же возникла наша. С наше же все проще. Оно тут используется в качестве чего-то - ты сам знаешь чего.
(В.И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа)
Наша взяла, хоть и рыло в крови.


Спасибо за ваше мнение! Когда мы задавали вопрос, у нас не было под руками печатных словарей. Теперь же мы заглянули в ФСРЯ под ред. А. И. Молоткова (1987). Выражение ГДЕ НАШЕ [ваше] НЕ ПРОПАДАЛО там имеется. Интересно, что есть и примеры его включения в предложение: Двести долларов жалко, но где наша не пропадала... (Анна Ткачева. Приворот).

Как раз хотела дополнить ответ по фразеологии.

Не знаю, где и что наша взяла, но вот общеизвестная информация из Сети:

Фразеология — раздел лингвистики, изучающий устойчивые сочетания, речевые обороты и выражения — фразеологические единицы.
Также фразеологией называют совокупность фразеологических единиц какого-либо языка. Термин «фразеология» происходит от греческих слов φράσις — выражение и λογος — понятие, учение.
В отличие от лексикологии, изучающей отдельные слова и словарную лексику, фразеология исследует НЕОДНОСЛОВНЫЕ ЕДИНИЦЫ языка: фразеологизмы (идиомы); поговорки; пословицы; речевые клише и фразеосхемы.

Итак, и пословицы, поговорки, и вообще любой речевой оборот, относится к фразеологии данного языка.  Туда же относятся   фразеологизмы, которые изучают по  Виноградову. Выделяют три основных вида: идиомы, фразеологические единства и фразеологические сочетания тема на форуме

Таким образом, надо понимать, что пословицу можно считать речевым фразеологическим оборотом в общем смысле. Но если по Виноградову, то это не фразеологизм.

Ну под фразеологизмом я понимаю языковую (внутреннюю) бессмыслицу наделенную народным (внешним) смыслом. Например "заруби себе на носу". "наша взяла" итд. Какая наша, что взяла, бред на бреде, но народ прекрасно все понимает. Понятно, что осмысленные пословицы постепенно могут стать бессмысленными фразеологизмами. То есть тут граница не четкая

Вы любопытно все понимаете, не по Виноградову)  Наша пословица больше на поговорку похожа, а там уже разрешается образность с метафоричностью.  Так что можно считать, что поговорки ближе к фразеологизмам, но все же до них не дотягивают.  Все слова одного фразеологизма — один член предложения. А тут вроде бы не один. Так что пусть это будет  особый "поговорочный бред".
